# Cordova inappbrowser not working in android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm working on a ionic based webview project by using cordova inappbrowser plugin, I could run it properly by using "ionic serve" command but when i try to run it on android it stucks at blank screen.

```
.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope) {

$scope.openCordovaWebView = function()
{
 // Open cordova webview if the url is in the whitelist otherwise opens in app browser
window.open('https://google.com','_self','location=no'); 

};
```

Comment: I think you are calling inappbrowser when plugins are not ready. Please check for device ready then call plugin.

Comment: You should provide a console log, it may help, if any error is raised.

Regarding Hardik's advice, you can wrap your call to `window.open` in `ionic.Platform.ready(function() {});`. The `function` given to `ready()` will be executed as soon as the cordova platform is ready (or immediately if it already is).

Answer (score 0):

Have you install

```
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser ?
```

In terminal type:

```
cordova plugin list
```

in your project's root folder.
Also

```
cordova plugin
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this after you have the plug in installed, in View:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="openInBrowser('https://www.google.com')">
    GOOGLE
</button>
```

then in the JS

```
myApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaInAppBrowser', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaInAppBrowser){

        $scope.openInBrowser = function(extUrl){

            $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

                var options = {
                    location: 'yes',
                    clearcache: 'yes',
                    toolbar: 'yes'
                  };

                $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(extUrl, '_system', options)
                .then(function(event) {
                  // success
                })
                .catch(function(event) {
                  // error
                });               

            }); // ./$ionicPlatform.ready
        };//--------------------------------------

 }]);
```